# Using Sparkline on Google Sheet

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I22Gg.png)

I just want to change color according to value but it's not working
any body knows reason?

Expecting

`D3=<10`, return "e04848"
`10<D3 AND D3<70`, return "e0b848"
`D3>=70` return "5789e6"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you also try replacing `D3=<10` to `D3<=10`